# How to clip unneccessary portion, to avoid ontap issue

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

[image]

I have used google map and added custom markers, (if that marker is for kid it will show dark blue marker with right bottom arrow or it will be red color left bottom arrow marker).

I have used custompainter to drawing this custom markers.  to showing the arrowhead in exact position, given container width (blue color) is 2x as expected.

onTapping the marke,that will show a customUIwidget corresponds to that.

My problem is if there are 2 or more markers near by, on tapping marker it showing adjacent(left/right side) marker's customUIwidget wrongly.

Is there any way to avoid showing my customUIwidget on tapping blue color area?

```
return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 45,
      width: 170, // 85,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: CustomMarker(
            iskid: widget.isKid)),
        child: Column(.... text widget....)
);
```

```
///painter
class CustomMarker extends CustomPainter {
  CustomMarker({this.isKid});
  final bool? isKid;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
final double height = size.height;
    final double markerHeight = height - 10;
    final double width = size.width / 2;
 if (!iskid!) {
        Path path = Path()
          ..moveTo(0, 0)
          ..lineTo(width, 0)
          ..lineTo(width, height + 2)
          ..lineTo(width - 10, markerHeight)
          ..lineTo(0, markerHeight)
          ..close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint1);
        canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);
      } else {
        Path path = Path()
          ..moveTo(width, 0)
          ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
          ..lineTo(size.width, markerHeight)
          ..lineTo(width + 10, markerHeight)
          ..lineTo(width, height + 2)
          ..close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint2);
        canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. No need to add extra width. There is option to move marker to left/right/top/bottom using anchor property available in marker

```
Marker(
              anchor: isKid
                  ? const Offset(0.0, 1.0)
                  : const Offset(1.0, 1.0),
              consumeTapEvents: true,....
)
```