# Is there any way to move a marker (some pixel left or right) on google_map?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

[image]
I tried to move the custom marker left/right based on requirement using Transform.translate/FractionalTranslation widgets, it moving but half portion cut-off.

```
      translation: isKid! ? Offset(0.5, 0) : Offset(-0.5, 0),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 45,
        width: 85,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: CustomMarker(
            iskid: widget.isKid)),
            child: Column(.... text widget....)
);
```

How to move without this issue?
please see this too
[How to clip unneccessary portion, to avoid ontap issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76684946/how-to-clip-unneccessary-portion-to-avoid-ontap-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.  There is option to move marker to left/right/top/bottom using anchor property available in marker

```
 Marker(
              anchor: isKid
                  ? const Offset(0.0, 1.0)
                  : const Offset(1.0, 1.0),
              consumeTapEvents: true,....
)
```